# MySQL INSERT with multiple SELECTS, with differing number of returned columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert into a table multiple values from multiple different tables. Here is a simple example (in practice this would be mostly useless, but if I posted my full queries it would be more complex to understand):

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    lastName VARCHAR(100),
    firstName VARCHAR(50),
    dob DATE,
    telNo VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE postcode (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    postcode VARCHAR(10),
);

CREATE TABLE name (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    lastName VARCHAR(100),
    firstName VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO postcode VALUES(21, "DN3 1SU");
INSERT INTO name VALUES(21, "Smith", "John"); 

INSERT INTO person (id, lastName, firstName, dob, telNo) VALUES (
    (SELECT id FROM postcode WHERE postcode="DN3 1SU"),
    (SELECT lastName, firstName FROM name WHERE id=21),
    "1991-12-20",
    "075935678923"
);
```

I am basically trying to construct a new row in a table based upon data from other tables (where the number of columns I take from each table differs) and some literal values.

With the method I've currently used VALUES does not accept the second SELECT statement because it's providing two columns, rather than one.

Comment: Because I'm not inserting multiple rows, just one, where the values in the row are derrived from different sources.

Comment: Illustrated with a more concrete example

Comment: Does postcode's ID relate to name's ID? Is it a coincidence that they are both 21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an `INSERT ... SELECT` append query:

```
INSERT INTO `person` (id, lastName, firstName, dob, telNo)
SELECT p.id, n.lastName, n.firstName, '1991-12-20', '075935678923'
FROM `postcode` p
INNER JOIN `name` n ON p.id = n.id AND n.id = 21
WHERE p.postcode = 'DN3 1SU'
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided your condition allows for it, this should work. You have five columns to fill, you need 5 values separated by commas.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5) VALUES (
    (SELECT val1 FROM table2 WHERE condition),
    (SELECT val2 FROM table3 WHERE condition),
    (SELECT val3 FROM table3 WHERE condition),
    "literal1",
    "literal2"
);
```

Comment: The issue here though is that val2 and val3 both need to come from the same query. I could simply run the same query twice and just get val2 and val3 that way, but then I'm running the same select query twice needlessly.

Comment: No, you're only running it once needlessly. I said it works, I didn't say it was optimal but, given that it does return the correct values, it's probably better than your version that returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Gather all your data (that you want to insert) in one place by using JION operation and then use INSERT Command.

```
INSERT INTO person (id, lastName, firstName, dob, telNo) 
(
SELECT t2.id, t2.lastName, t2.firstName, t2.aa, t2.bb
from
(SELECT id FROM postcode WHERE postcode="DN3 1SU") t1
INNER JOIN    
(SELECT id,lastName, firstName, '1991-12-20' as aa, '075935678923' as bb FROM name WHERE id=21) t2
ON t1.id=t2.id 
);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Union is used to combine multiple rows from different select statements. I am trying to combine multiple columns from different select statements.

Comment: in new case, you can use JOINS between tables and then get final one SELECT and insert it at once.

Comment: I didn't change my question, I just provided a more clear example at the request of Parafait. Join doesn't work either, because join requires that you have two tables that share one column in common, but I my tables don't share any common columns